# urllib2.urlopen raises HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, url, pdf, download, urllib2

I'm trying to download a pdf using urllib2. The problem is that it raises `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`.

I suppose that the problem is probably in form of url. I've tried to apply `urllib2.quote` method but it did not helped.

URL: `http://www.epi.sk/Main/Download.aspx?fn=\OV\15\OV2015072a$ce10308b-264c-400a-81ad-e643c08a7364.pdf&ofn=15\OV2015072a.pdf`

```
def download_file(download_url,name):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    with open(name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.read())

download_file('http://www.epi.sk/Main/Download.aspx?fn=\OV\15\OV2015072a$ce10308b-264c-400a-81ad-e643c08a7364.pdf&ofn=15\OV2015072a.pdf','files.pdf')
```

Do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your backslashes is causing a portion of your string to be interpreted as an escape sequence:

```
'http://www.epi.sk/Main/Download.aspx?fn=\OV\15\OV2015072a$ce10308b-264c-400a-81ad-e643c08a7364.pdf&ofn=15\OV2015072a.pdf'
                                            ^^^
```

`\15` is interpreted an escape sequence for a carriage return:

```
>>> '\15'
'\r'
```

Make the string a raw string by prefixing it with `r` and Python won't interpret these escape sequences:

```
>>> r'\15'
'\\15'
```

Comment: Agreed.  Please change your string to a raw string so python doesn't think you are trying to use an escape sequence.